# how to calculate quartiles in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rows, percentile

i am using postgresql, i have the table with nearly 1000000 rows:

```
  CREATE TABLE Data(
  id varchar(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  jan INT,
  feb INT,
  mar INT,
  apr INT,
  may INT,
  jun INT,
  jul INT,
  aug INT,
  sep INT, 
  oct INT,
  nov INT,
  dec INT);
```

And i want to get the quartiles

For example:

```
ID    jan  feb  mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
A10    1    2   3    4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```

I want to output as:

```
ID    Q1  Q2  Q3 Q4
A10    3  6   9  12
```

How can i do that in postgresql?

Comment: You can do it with [`CASE - WHEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we're happy to help you - but it's a good idea for you to google a bit and have a go at it yourself first, then show us what you tried (even if it is broken) and we can then help you fix the bits that don't work. eg here I'd google something like "SQL year quarter" or similar.

Comment: Please refine your question, as (by definition) only 3 [quartiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) could be produced; and you probably need something else. (From your example, it seems, you need the max month value from every season, is that right?)

Answer (score 1):

May be this will give you desired result:

```
Select id, 
       jan + feb + mar as Q1,
       apr + may + jun as Q2,
       jul + aug + sep as Q3,
       oct + nov + dec as Q4,
From Data
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the columns that make up the Quarters

```
select id
, (case 
     when jan>feb and jan>mar then jan
     when feb>jan and feb>mar then feb
     else mar END
       ) q1
...Similarly for q2,q3,q4
from table
```